# Python - MySQL Connector - Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm running a Python program, using mySQL connector, that uses a large amount of mySQL queries. The program stopped dead partway through and gave this error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1461 (42000): Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 16382)
```

Other questions I've seen regarding this error involve PHP or Propel. Is there a simple Python/mySQL solution (perhaps changing a mySQL variable) to fix/bypass this? I've also seen 'closing the query' as a suggestion; is that a thing, and is there a Pythonic way to do that?